# How does update function works in drools?

Tags: drools

How does update function works in drools? Does it cause the same rules fire again automatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need to read the manual: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/

Using `update` makes the rules engine aware that a fact has been modified. Therefore rules which depend upon that fact must be re-evaluated. This does have the effect that a rule may fire in an endless cycle. For instance, given the following DRL, you will see that the "Infinite loop" rule will activate continuously:

```
declare AreWeThereYet
    answer : boolean
end

rule "Are we there yet?"
when
    not AreWeThereYet()
then
    insert(new AreWeThereYet());
end

rule "Infinite loop"
    no-loop
when
    $question: AreWeThereYet()
then
    $question.setAnswer(false);
    update($question);
end
```

This is because the rules engine has been instructed by `update($question)`, that `$question` has changed and that it needs to re-evaluate it.

There are ways of preventing this though. Just put `no-loop` on the line between the rule name and `when` to prevent rules from re-activating as a result of their own consequences. Another rule attribute which can control this is `lock-on-active`.